# Flask-Testing and Flask-SQLAlchemy: first_or_404()

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-testing

I'm trying to test with **Flask-Testing** a **Flask-SQLAlchemy** model. More precisely a static method of this model that uses `first_or_404()` and I cannot find a way to make my test work.

Here a self contained example that highlight the issue:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.testing import TestCase

db = SQLAlchemy()

class ModelToTest(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'model_to_test'
    identifier = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False, primary_key=True)

    @staticmethod
    def get_by_identifier(identifier):
        return ModelToTest.query.filter_by(identifier=identifier).first_or_404()

class Config:
    DEBUG = True
    TESTING = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

class TestGetByIdentifier(TestCase):

    def create_app(self):
        app = Flask('test')
        app.config.from_object(Config())
        db.init_app(app)
        return app

    def setUp(self):
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()

    def test_get_by_identifier(self):
        self.assert404(ModelToTest.get_by_identifier('identifier'))
```

I got the error:

```
(my_env) PS C:\Dev\Test\Python\test_flask> nosetests-3.4.exe
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_get_by_identifier (test_flask.TestGetByIdentifier)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Dev\Test\Python\test_flask\test_flask.py", line 37, in test_get_by_identifier
    self.assert404(ModelToTest.get_by_identifier('identifier'))
  File "C:\Dev\Test\Python\test_flask\test_flask.py", line 13, in get_by_identifier
    return ModelToTest.query.filter_by(identifier=identifier).first_or_404()
  File "c:\\my_env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 431, in first_or_404
    abort(404)
  File "c:\\my_env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\exceptions.py", line 646, in __call__
    raise self.mapping[code](*args, **kwargs)
werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound: 404: Not Found

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.913s
```

So the line `self.assert404(ModelToTest.get_by_identifier('identifier'))` does generate an exception in the `first_or_404()` call and this exception is a `werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound`, it does not seems to be what's expected by `self.assert404()`.

Requirements to run this test are:

- flask
- flask-sqlalchemy
- flask-testing

It is worth noting that when I use the function in the application it behaves as expected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I'm quoting the answer I've received on GitHub:

https://github.com/jarus/flask-testing/issues/89

> I believe this is a misunderstanding about the way to drive the test.
>   The `first_or_404` function will indeed raise a `NotFound` exception. When
>   in the context of the request, the exception will bubble up, be
>   handled, and turn into a 404 http response, which is what
>   flask-testing is looking for.
>
> However, you are not in the context of a request in this case since
>   you are calling the method directly and it is simply resulting in an
>   exception. You could do this to make the test work
>
> ```
> from werkzeug.exceptions import NotFound
>
> def test_get_by_identifier(self):
>     with self.assertRaises(NotFound):
>         ModelToTest.get_by_identifier('identifier')
> ```
>
> Or, you can stick that function behind a route and test it using
>   self.client which will correctly give you a 404 http response.
>   However, testing the exception (without the use of flask-testing) may
>   be more appropriate in this case given the level you are testing at.